# Error when restoring WordPress backup - images not showing in peosts

Tags: php, wordpress

We recently had a web server fail on us.  Luckily, by sheer coincidence, it failed the day after we did a massive backup and image of the drives, so all the data was saved.

Today I installed our backup server (exactly the same specs, with exactly the same make and model hardware) so we could get back up and running.  Everything went well and the site is working, however, the images are not showing in the posts.  I have confirmed they are all in their respective directories in wp-content/uploads, but none are appearing on the posts themselves.

The site was working perfectly before the server failed, and the backups and image completed successfully.  The specs of the web server, control panel, phpmysql, or WordPress itself have not changed and everything should have worked as soon as the image was restored, but it doesn't.

WordPress version is 4.8.1, every plugin is up-to-date and there are over 3600 posts which I would rather not have to edit by hand...

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this images issue?

Comment: Did you reinstate everything via images of the HDD? I.e. didn't recreate the website in cPanel and just copy the files back in? Also in the inspector in your browser, what error/messages do you see for the broken images? 404s?

Comment: I did everything via a HDD image (same make/model/size HDD).  The new server is exactly the same as the old on in every way.  Literally only difference is serial numbers.

For the error message in console inspector I get: 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: If everything is *exactly* the same then it would work, of course. Can you get on command line? How do the owner/group/permissions look for those images?

Comment: All permissions are the same as before too.

Comment: The site works, and all posts show up, just the images in those posts are not showing.  Since I posted this question, sales staff have started putting up new posts and those images are showing correctly, just not the older, existing images.

Comment: Can you post the full URL (ommitting domain if you prefer) from the `<img>` tag for a broken and a working image?

Comment: Bizarrely, I came into work this morning and now all the images are showing up fine.  No-one changed anything (I'm the only one that would know how to), but it works again.

Comment: I still had a screen open with the console errors and the only difference between a working image and a non-working (at the time) image is the month folder;

not working: .../wp-content/uploads/2016/10/image.jpg
working: .../wp-content/uploads/2016/11/image.jpg